# Closing Angular 1.5 Material mdDialog from controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

In an Angular 1.5 component I'm showing a Material mdDialog, which itself has an embedded component:

```
                $mdDialog.show({
                        controller: function($scope, $log) {
                          $scope.notify=function() {
                            $log.debug("need to cancel");
                            $mdDialog.hide();
                          }
                        },
                        template: "<md-dialog aria-label='Add Foobar'><new-foobar-panel on-cancel='notify()'></new-foobar-panel></md-dialog>",
                        targetEvent: ev,
                        clickOutsideToClose: true,
                        fullscreen: true
                    });
```

When the embedded component invokes the `onCancel()` callback, the dialog's controller closes the dialog by using `$mdDialog.hide()`.

But that seems sort of messy. The documentation for `$mdDialog` says that it will close the last opened dialog, but that seems sort of lazy and wishy-washy. I'm sure there is some case with many components and dialogs that would cause this to fail. I'm inside the controller of the dialog after all --- shouldn't there be a reference to the dialog instance I can use to close it directly?

I tried this:

```
                var dialog = $mdDialog.show({
                        controller: function($scope, $log) {
                          $scope.notify=function() {
                            $log.debug("need to cancel");
                            dialog.hide();
                          }
```

But that doesn't work; perhaps a promise is returned instead of a dialog.

So am I stuck with calling `$mdDialog.hide()` (the global service!!) and hoping that refers to the dialog I'm working with? (That's not very good modularization.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the [documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDialog) says

> ```
> // Close the specified dialog instance and resolve with 'finished' flag
> // Normally this is not needed, just use '$mdDialog.hide()' to close
> // the most recent dialog popup.
>
> function closeAlert() {
>   $mdDialog.hide( alert, "finished" );
>   alert = undefined;
> }
> ```

where `alert` is the dialog instance previously build. So if you actually need to refer to a specific instance of dialog and not the last one, you can use the above method to close it.

Comment: Oh, I get it now! I had missed that. Just what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Very odd: when I use `$mdDialog.hide(dialog, "finished")`, the `.then(function(answer)` is never invoked! I set a breakpoint and everything, but it never hits it. What could be going on?

Comment: Actually it seems that `$mdDialog.cancel(dialog)` will resolve the promise, but not `$mdDialog.hide(dialog)`! I can get `$mdDialog.hide()` to resolve the dialog, but not `$mdDialog.hide(dialog)`. Surely there's something I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?